# how we can do automatic backup for compute engine disk everyday ? in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created instance in compute engine with windows server 2012. i cant see any option to take automatic backup for instance disk database everyday. there is option of snapshot but we need to operate this manually. please suggest any way to backup automatically and can be restore able on a single click. if is there any other possibility using cloud SQL storage or any other storage please recommend.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an API to take snapshots, see API section here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_your_snapshot

You can write a simple app to get triggered from Cron or something to take a snapshot periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You have no provision for automatic back up for compute engine disk. But you can do a manual disk backup by creating a snapshot.

Best alternative way is to create a bucket and move your files there. Google cloud buckets have automated back up facility available.

Cloud storage and cloud SQL are your options for automated back ups in google cloud.